Should the same language be used for question title and body?
It seems like we have settled on allowing questions in both Italian and English (good).
But today I saw this question, which has an english title, an italian body english answers and mixed comments. Shouldn't at least title and body of the question be coherent? I ask because there may be non-obvious points, such as SEO, to consider.

I think we should have title and body in the same language, I have fixed the title of that question.

Looking at the issue the other way around, I would say that I cannot find any good reason to have two different languages for subject and body of the question (apart confusing the reader, which is of course a reasonable reason if your aim is creatng caos in the world).
Also, it would 'confuse' spiders and other automated tools which deal with the difficult task of assigning a semantic to web contents.
